# Upload and display a MS word Document in Android

Tags: java, android, ms-word

I need to create an app that takes a MS word document and lets the user of the app interact with the pages meaning viewing each page separately, zooming, going forward and backward.

Comment: I was wondering if there was an API that could help me do that. With the gdoc api, the user needs to authenticated himself in order to see the document. Is it possible to display a MS word via XML, or use the document class.

Answer (score 6):

There is no API built into Android for reading Microsoft documents.

I would estimate implementing what you seek to take over 100 engineer-months. There are only a few apps ever written that can display Word documents, and only 2-3 of these have been ported to Android.

I would recommend you do a server-side conversion of the Word document to HTML, then display it in a `WebView` widget, if you want something that takes less engineering time to implement.

Comment: can u suggest me, what is the best way for converting .docx file into html. I have used opi for converting .doc file into html.