# Does anyone know how to open MS-Word document in android?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to open ms-word documents in android?

please give me the name of the API that I can use to develop ms-word viewer?

I want to develop ms-word viewer. please help me.

Comment: upload the document in Google Docs then view the document from there?

Comment: you want to open MS-Word files, (.doc) in Android, not the whole MS-Word, right? I was confused by your question's title. :P

Comment: I have heard that MS Office 2007 (and perhaps above than that) use XML for storing data, maybe you can devise a way to read that XML!?

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3225071/741249) there is no API for MS-Word

Answer (score -1):

I agree with what Sheikh Aman says. MS office 2007 files are docx files. x stands for xml.
To view the contents of say  "data.docx" file, rename the docx file to "data.zip" and open the zip file. You can parse the contents of these xml files by using , Simple API for XML (SAX) or the Document Object Model (DOM) as both are available on Android.

Link has details about xml parsing etc.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: If you try to open a .docx file in a text editor you will see that it isn't simply xml and that your suggested approach will not work.