# Read and display a ms word doc on android

Tags: android

I want to read a microsoft word document and display the same on android.In iphone webview does it all but there is no such kind of support in android.I have searched many open source jars but of no avail.Please can anybody guide me or anyone has done this kind of thing please help becoz i am struggling to get this work for a long time

Comment: There is no API built into Android for reading Microsoft documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224986/upload-and-display-a-ms-word-document-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @VinaySShenoy Hi, the link you have given is quite old. I support this question. I am facing same problem :(

Comment: @androidsanta Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that there still isn't a complete solution for doing the same.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy Is there any workaround that i can use with some extra effort. Please guide me as i am stuck really bad.

Comment: You can try Apache POI - http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Android itself does not support rendering of .doc or .ppt files. A public intent may be used that will allow your app to reuse other apps' activities to display these document types. But this will only work for a phone that has an app installed that supports this Intent.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html
If you have some app installed then you can use the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String type = "application/msword";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if no valid msword app is present then it will display a toast that no application capable of handling this type of content

Comment: @Antrromet Using the above idea i was able to trigger Quickoffice application to open my word document. But i am facing "`File cannot be opened`" error. Can i know what could be an issue? Because, when i open the same word file manually using quick office, it is getting opened.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are not libraries for reading MS Office documents. I see only 3 ways to do it.

1. You can write you own MS Word analogue for the Android
2. You can rewrite one of the open-source office suite (OpenOffice/LibreOffice)
3. You can use Google Docs.
4. You can use some other format or use converter.

I think, only third and fourth ways are realizable.

Comment: 3rd point requires 3g/wifi for using not for offline usage that is a problem with google docs